# How to prevent a number from using number1"E"number2

Tags: javascript, integer

I need help because if I try to write a number that has a whole bunch of zeroes, it will come out as num1Enum2.

ie: for a googol it would write "1E100".

I want it to actually write the number, rather than the shortened form. How would I do this?

Note: I want it to still be an integer rather than a string.

Comment: What do you mean by wanting it to still be an integer? Ultimately, the number is always converted to a string internally before it is printed anywhere.

Comment: I mean to have the integer still stored as a variable, and not manipulated by any string methods. I also don't want a second string that has the value of the variable, so I have a string and an integer.

Comment: Keeping it stored as an integer is trivial (you can just make a copy if necessary) and not manipulating it with any string methods is impossible (that's how output works; you just don't usually don't see the string methods). There is no builtin way to tell JS to write it fully, therefore you have to write that method yourself, using appropriate string operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a big number handling library, like [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js).  Otherwise, your only solution will be to split your big numbers into arrays and write your own math functions to manipulate them -- something like this function to treat an array as an integer and increment it:

```
var longVal=[0];

// inherits global array longVal[]
// increments each element from right to left
function inc() {
    for (var i=longVal.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (++longVal[i] == 10) {
            longVal[i] = 0;
            if (!i) {
                longVal.splice(0, 0, 0);
                i++;
            }
            continue;
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

I think if you exceed the length limit of your array, you could probably change the `if (++longVal[i] == 10)` line to something like `if (++longval[i] == 1000000000)` for great justice, but you'd have to left pad each array element except the first with zeros to make it ten digits.  I haven't tested that though.  My answer is the concept, rather than the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you "write out" a number, you get a string. Period. "Writing out" means outputting a sequence of characters that represent the number. But that's what a string is: a sequence of characters.

A number like 1E100 is too big to represent as a normal-sized integer, even internally. To get a value that big as an integer, you'll have to use some sort of library to represent big integers. Search around for one. There are several, with names like "BigInt", "BigInteger", "BigNumber", "LongDecimal" and so on. They should all be able to store internally arbitrarily large integer values, and should all provide a way to turn that value into a string, which you can then write out. Pick one you like.